# How to set size of collection view programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a collection view which forms a grid 15 x 15. I want to set its height and width to be 0.5 (or some multiple) of the view height in which it is contained. I have done this in the storyboard and set the aspect ratio to 1:1.

[image]

My problem is that when I rotate the screen to landscape the grid is no longer 15 x 15.

[image]

I can set the height directly in the storyboard e.g. 300 x 300 but then I run into problems with getting it to fit differing devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue, because height in landscape mode is lower then in portrait. So, if you set width & height constraints of `UICollectionView` to be equal(with some multiplier) to `superview` it's automatically change it size when you rotate device

What you can do it's connect width & height outlets in code and set appropriated values in `viewDidLoad` method

Answer (score 0):

You can add equal width and equal height constraint to your collection view with respect to superview in which it is. And then edit constraints multiplier to 0.5 as shown in image below-
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. Also, I'm aiming for an aspect ratio of 1:1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
extension MYViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/15, height: collectionView.frame.height/15)
    }
}
```

add these lines too

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        guard let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
            super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
            return
        }
        flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    }
```